# Kubernete: ask a L4 load balance solution for a non-cloud cluster

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

I built a Kubernete cluster in local data center. There are 4 nodes and 1 master.
Looking for a L4 loadbalance solution for internal service.

```
root@niubi01:/home/mesos# kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS         AGE
niubi01   Ready,master   7d
niubi02   Ready          7d
niubi03   Ready          7d
niubi04   Ready          7d
niubi05   Ready          7d
```

Assume we have three Pods with 'hello world' web service. A service with exposed External IP is created with 'NodePort'. The external IP is 'Nodes' and port is 30145.

```
root@niubi01:/home/mesos# kubectl get service
NAME               CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
example-service    10.100.220.21    <nodes>       8080:30145/TCP   6d
```

As the document mentioned, we can access any node IP to access this 'hello world' service. Like:

```
curl http://niubi01:30145
curl http://niubi02:30145
curl http://niubi03:30145
curl http://niubi04:30145
curl http://niubi05:30145
```

from outside.
The problem is we can't guarantee any node is active forever, even master. Which URL should we take to use? 
How to do a LoadBalance like Haproxy to provide high availability to this service?
Should we have another server provide loadbalance sevice between these 5 addresses? Seeking for any better solution for this case.

Comment: You may use DNS round robin, create a DNS record with multiple end points and use a watchdog service to keep the DNS record updated with a list of live nodes? It does seem you will need to build a load balancer solution in front of it though.

Comment: Hi - you were asking for a L4 load balancer, but mix in products like Nginx or HAproxy from the above layers. Should the question be changed to avoid future confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have noticed, you would have to setup a custom loadbalancer to make this work. This loadbalancer must be external to your cluster and configured by yourself.

I would suggest that you read through the concepts of [`Ingress`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/) and [`ingress-controller`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/#ingress-controllers). Especially the [nginx-ingress-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/controllers/nginx) is very useful here.

The advantage would be that you would only have to set up your custom external loadbalancer only once and not for all services you'd like to expose. Your loadbalancer should balance traffic to the ingress controller, which will then do the internal load balancing based on the provided `Ingress` resources.

To deploy the ingress controller, it should be enough to do the following:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress/master/examples/deployment/nginx/default-backend.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress/master/examples/deployment/nginx/nginx-ingress-controller.yaml
```

The first line creates a `default-backend` which is used for all unmatched ingresses. It basically just returns `404`

The second line creates a `Deployment` with 1 replica by default. In a prod environment, you may want to change the replica count either by scaling the Deployment or by using a local modified copy of the `nginx-ingress-controller.yaml` file. Also, I'd advise to use dedicated nodes (by using DaemonSet+NodeAffinity+Taints+Tolerations) for the ingress-controller in case you expect a lot of traffic.

The ingress-controller now runs without being exposed. I assume that exposing the controller is not part of the examples as this varies too much depending on the infrastructure in use. In your case, you should create a Kubernetes `Service` that exposes the ingress-controller as `NodePort` by deploying this resource:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingres-controller-svc
  labels:
    name: nginx-ingres-controller-svc
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30080
      name: http
    - port: 443
      nodePort: 30443
      name: https
  selector:
    k8s-app: nginx-ingress-controller
```

Please note that the `nodePort` is explicitly specified here. This makes life easier when you configure your external loadbalancer.

After all this is set-up, you can create `Ingress` resources to direct external traffic into your internal services. For example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.company.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: example-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

If you have your data centers DNS setup to resolve `example.company.org` to the external load balancer, calling it will bring you directly to the `example-service`

All this probably sounds more complicated then just using a NodePort and changing configuration of the external loadbalancer for new services. But if it is set-up once, configuration and automation are simplified a lot. It also gives a ton of new features which would have to be implemented manually otherwise. For example, the nginx-ingress-controller natively supports basic auth by simply adding an annotation to the `Ingress` resource. It also supports letsencrypt when used in combination with `kube-lego`. As said in the beginning, you should read the documentation regarding ingress to figure out what it brings for free.

Comment: "This loadbalancer must be external to your cluster and configured by yourself." Does it mean I need install ingress & ingress-controller at another kubernete cluster? If it is, how the 2nd cluster communicate with the original one? I actually tried to do this way at master node but not works. Thanks!

Comment: There are 2 loadbalancers in play here, the first is the ingress-controller which runs inside the cluster. The second one is a load balancer that you'd have to create/configure somewhere outside of the cluster (completely out of Kubernetes). The second one points to the ingress-controller and is only meant as an integration point into your existing infrastructure. If, for example, you already have a LB solution running in your DC, you could configure it to point to the ingress-controller.

Answer (score 2):

independent from where your `LoadBalancer` is located you could just have a virtual IP address load balanced between your nodes and include it in your service definition as shown [in the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#external-ips):

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9376
  externalIPs:
  - 80.11.12.10
```

Once the traffic for this IP (`80.11.12.10`) hits any of the nodes, `kube-proxy` will redirect it to your service.

One option to implement this would be using Pacemaker on the nodes as described in many [blog posts](http://jensd.be/156/linux/building-a-high-available-failover-cluster-with-pacemaker-corosync-pcs). But also having a dedicated load balancer in front of the cluster would work just fine.

The benefit of using virtual IPs is that you don't have to mess with the NodePorts in firewalls or related configuration. Another benefit is that this isn't limited to HTTP traffic.

The downside is that the configuration of the external load balancer and the IP assignment for the service is not automated and has to be done manually. To mitigate this issue you could either implement your own provider (see other [provider implementations on Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/e7950e6f4961595e6c9df878bbc6dd520c792d03/pkg/cloudprovider/providers)) or you could read the service configuration from etcd and use that as source for the configuration of your external load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

If the LB is external, then you need to have some sort of keepalive/probe to determine which nodes should receive the traffic.

A round-robin design does NOT accomplish this, as you are just sending traffic to a black hole every 1/n times.

You should also consider a dynamic way to ADD new nodes in case your cluster grows.  In this case, you likely need to use the kubernetes operator.

There are prebuilt and ready to use options to do this from Netris/Metallb.

We recently wrote an article explaining this sort of design/implementation here: https://www.netris.ai/cloud-like-load-balancer/